# do/ conduct a physical examination (I'm the patient, which verb should I use?)

Tags: word-request

> In order to apply for a working visa, I need to _____ a physical
>   examination and send the results to the department of immigrantion.

Which verb should I use?

I think the doctor perform/ do the physical examination, not me, I'm the patient.

So I don't know which verb I should use in the above sentence.

Comment: Please confirm, you created this sentence yourself, didn't you? And the word choice is your own, this sentence is not from an English textbook, is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I edited the question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Typo... and **send** the results

Comment: *Undergo* is sometimes used in BrE, but *have* is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence

> In order to apply for a working visa, I need to _____ a physical examination and send the results to the department of immigration.

You need something which you currently do not have in your possession to send to immigration.

You need to

> get

a physical exam, just as you would "get" a book, a pen, or a ticket.

> In order to apply for a working visa, I need to ***get*** a physical examination and send the results to the department of immigration.

Once you "get" the exam, you will "have" the results

> In order to apply for a working visa, I need to ***have*** a physical examination and send the results to the department of immigration.